# Created a Flow for a SharePoint list but I don't want it to be a "personal" Flow

Tags: flow

The flow I created works well, but it runs under my security context and every now and again, I have to edit the flow and refresh security.

I want it to "just work" against the list without being tied to me.  How can I create a flow that's "owned" by the list or site, so that all owners of the site can manage it?

Answer (score 0):

You can share a Flow with other users, group or list.

You can find Share button near Edit button, under "My Flow".

[Official documentation to Create Team Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/create-team-flows#create-a-team-flow)

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, but only the people I share it with can edit it.  What that doesn't solve is running outside of my personal credentials, that have to be refreshed.

Comment: You can't choose the context, some action run with the context of Flow user and other with the context of the connection (that you can set on the Flow)

Comment: I suggest trying to use a trigger that provides that feature. Otherwise, the service doesn't know who start the Flow.

Comment: it is not uncommon that to have the workflow functioning even after you leave, you ask IT a system account (with licenses) and use it for Flows and Power Apps. The workflow will not be associated with a 'person' account

Comment: Susan, if you'll post a response with that detail and a little explanation why, I'll mark it as the correct response.